# Reference to a particular result of Scholl and Faltings

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, p-adic-hodge-theory

Let $f=\sum_{n\geq 1} a_n q^n$ be a normalized eigenform which is supersingular and crystalline at a prime $p$ and let $V_f$ be the associated crystalline representation, then it follows from the work of Scholl and Faltings that the characteristic polynomial of the $\Phi$ operator on $D_{cris}(V_f^*)$ is $X^2-a_p X+p^{k-1}$. This is alluded to in "Explicit reduction modulo p of certain $2$-dimensional crystalline representations"- Buzzard and Gee.

I've been trying to find the location of this result by looking through some of Scholl's papers, in which paper can it be found?

Comment: My guess is that what you get from Scholl and Faltings is simply that the associated Galois representation is crystalline. What you want should follow from this and some comparison/compatibility results saying the the characteristic polynomial of the $\Phi$ operator is the same as the characteristic polynomial of $Frob_p$ acting on the l-adic representation for $l\neq p$ but I don't know a precise reference for this.

Comment: Did you check Scholl's "Motives for modular forms", Inventiones 1990?

Comment: Kato in his Astérisque paper refers to Saito (Modular forms and p-adic Hodge theory, Inventiones 1997) for this result.

Comment: In fact Saito determines the char poly of $\Phi$ without any assumption on $f $.

Comment: @Laurent, I did take a cursory look at that paper of Scholl's.

Comment: @François, thanks, yes that's what I was looking for!